# UIButton doesn't get iOS 6 styling in compatibility mode in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios7

I am working on an app that has not yet been redesigned for iOS 7.  There are a few new features being added that I want to deliver in an app update, but I want the app to run in iOS 6 "compatibility mode" on iOS 7.  I have set the Base SDK to iOS 6.1.  When I build and run everything looks fine in the iOS 6 Simulator.  However, in the iOS 7 Simulator, all elements look iOS 6-ish with the exception of the UIButtons which are all borderless.

Is this expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

I tested this using a simple app with one button and one switch.

iOS 6 Simulator:

[image: iOS 6]

iOS 7 Simulator:

[image: iOS 7]

Notice how the switch remains iOS 6-like in iOS 7 but the button does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience you need to work and submit the app using xCode 4.6 if you want to retain the iOS 6 UI. Testing is a little tedious in iOS 7 but you can do it but installing the ad hoc app on your iOS 7 device.

**Update**

as @rmaddy mentions in the comments, you can build directly from Xcode 4.6 to iOS 7. Use your iOS 7 device with xCode 5 before doing so.

Comment: I _believe_ that Xcode 5 updated my storyboard such that it won't be openable under Xcode 4.6.  If that's the case, what a pain!

Comment: @KDaker You can use Xcode 4.x to run and debug development builds on a device with iOS 7. No need for adhoc builds and deployments. Works for me.

Comment: @mharper open the .xib or storyboard in Xcode 5, in the file inspector choose "open in xCode 4.6" and save it. You should be able to open it in Xcode 4.6 now.

Comment: @rmaddy how do you do that?

Comment: @KDaker I just do it. Nothing special. Though it may require that you once use Xcode 5 against the device. Once you do that then it should work with Xcode 4.x.

Comment: @rmaddy very interesting. It works now. It must have been a build on Xcode 5 because I remember it complaining about the iOS version before.

Comment: @KDaker Interestingly, after setting the storyboard to "Open in Xcode 4.6," I then built & ran it in the iOS 7 Simulator from Xcode 5.  Button appearance is restored, but I still have the slight layout problems courtesy of iOS 7.  Heading to Xcode 4.6 now.

Comment: @KDaker What iPhone are your running iOS 7 on? When I try running on my iPhone 5S from Xcode 4.6, it tells me: Xcode does not know how to run code on "arm64" devices.

Comment: I have an iPhone 5. Thats obviously an issue with the 64 bit processor of the 5s. I think only Xcode 5 would support the new architecture. Try with an older device if you have one, if not then i guess you'll have to go the ad hoc route.

Comment: Charging up the iPhone 5 as we speak. :-)

Comment: OK I can run the app on my iOS 7 iPhone 5 from Xcode 4.6, so we have a winner. Just for fun, I tried installing the iOS 7 Simulator in the Xcode 4.6 package.  It allowed me to fire up the app on the simulator but then crashed complaining "iOS Simulator could not find the SDK. The SDK may need to be reinstalled."  Don't know if that's a soluble problem since iOS 7 is "from the future" for Xcode 4.6. Anyway...